# Is it a good idea to get the recommendation letter from the head of a professional organization?

Tags: masters, recommendation-letter

For master's admission, the letter of recommendation is essential. It also makes impact on admission decision. Usually, the recommendation letters are obtained from academic professors.

Is it a good idea to get the recommendation letter from the head of a professional organization, who is not the head of my programs?

Comment: Can you describe your relation to this professional organisation?

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov I am a student member of that professional organization.Moreover,the head is also an internationally well-known figure.

Comment: Normally, the letter of recommendation explains what the writer about you.  If this guy does not know you, then probably you should not ask him for a recommendation.

Comment: @ GEdgar I think that guy personally knows me because we have exchanged emails several times.But he is not much aware about my knowledge area,skills.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, the letter of recommendation should present you, as a candidate, to your potential employer. As such, it should be from someone who:

1. Knows you in a professional capacity.
2. Knows you in the capacity which is (at least partly) relevant to the position you apply for.

To successfully learn on the master program, the candidate shall have a certain set of skills (e.g. knowledge of a particular subject), but also soft skills (commitment, dedication, self-motivation, teamwork, responsibility, ability to work independently, leadership, etc.). If the head of your professional organisation can emphasise these attributes in their letter, and justify them using examples and evidence, it is a (very) good idea to have the recommendation letter from them.